# used buff/cache memory increased suddenly in ubuntu 16 machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-memory, ram

In one of my ubuntu 16 production instance memory used by buffer/cache shot up suddenly.

We have not done any change in the machine.

Attaching screenshot and snapshot of free output.

[image: free o/p]

[image: Screenshot]

```
root@xxxxx~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G         37G        4.7G        2.5G        209G        210G
Swap:          5.7G        176M        5.5G
root@xxxxx:~# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            251          37           4           2         209         210
Swap:             5           0           5
```

1. Is this something to worry?
2. How can we find what caused the spike and reason for the utilization.

Comment: Some process did a lot of I/O around 2020-09-01 06:00:00. The data accessed is left in the cache because nothing else has needed the RAM since. If it is needed in the future, the Kernel can re-use it instantly, because it is already written to backing store. Cache is essentially free memory, but with known content that may possibly be requested again.

Comment: Notice the RAM is double-counted -- cache, and still available.